# Magento 2.2.5: _init() return error " Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, extend, memory

I'm doing "Banner Slider", and I'm following module-catalog/category.
So when i trying to copy this file:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection.php

I found that class was extends this class `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection`.
 I know we should extends `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`.

But when i try to follow them, it throw an error of memory when i using the `init()` function like this:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(\Aht\BannerSlider\Model\Slide::class, \Aht\BannerSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Slide::class);
}
```

Here is my

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Slide\Collection.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Administrator
 * Date: 13/07/2018
 * Time: 3:31 CH
 */

namespace Aht\BannerSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Slide;


// extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection
class Collection extends \Aht\BannerSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

/**
 * Define resource model
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(\Aht\BannerSlider\Model\Slide::class, \Aht\BannerSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Slide::class);
}

public function addAttributeToSelect($attribute, $joinType = false)
{
    return parent::addAttributeToSelect($attribute, $joinType);
}
}
```

Here is my

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Aht\BannerSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Collection;

/**
 * Catalog EAV collection resource abstract model
 * Implement using different stores for retrieve attribute values
 *
 * @api
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class AbstractCollection extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $eavConfig,
            $resource,
            $eavEntityFactory,
            $resourceHelper,
            $universalFactory,
            $connection
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: WHy you don't use `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection` ?

Comment: because the `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection` dont have addAttributeToSelect() function. I need it in the copy of file `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product.php`

Comment: I've create a same file as "Product.php" and named it "Slide.php"  for the same content.

Comment: Even if it doesn't have addAttributeToFIlter, you can always use addFieldToFilter  to filter your collection.